# SikaFix Foundation repair kit -are you supposed to cut the injection Ts and remove them and the concrete that covers them?

Tags: repair, foundation, crack

The instructions for [this product](https://www.homedepot.ca/product/sika-concrete-crack-injection-fix-kit/1000172324) seem to have been written by someone who had nothing to do with it
After watching their own vide it is not clear what happens with the Ts attached to the wall and if the concrete stays or needs to be removed
https://youtu.be/urTPztDzpaE

Comment: Snap the nozzles off afterward and cut flush if need be. (If the part that's hot glued to the wall stays, leave it. Otherwise patch.) If the wall is to look nice, feather out the repair with more hydraulic cement. This video isn't bad, except he forgot to spray water into the crack before the mortar stage, which probably impacted his results: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R-SC0-jFJj0

Comment: For an instructional it leaves out things that the home owner might miss ..the pro does not really need these instructions.